# how to install libstdc++4.7 for compiling llvm compiler on centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, llvm, libstdc++

I am trying to compile llvm in centos6. already followed [this_thread](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos) to install gcc 4.7 and 4.8. but I am getting the next error message :

```
../llvm/configure --prefix=/opt/llvm/installation

checking for clang... clang
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for clang++... clang++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking whether clang works... yes
checking whether GCC or Clang is our host compiler... clang
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking type of operating system we're going to host on... Linux
checking type of operating system we're going to target... Linux
checking target architecture... x86_64
checking whether Clang is new enough... yes
checking whether Clang will select a modern C++ standard library... no
configure: error:
We detected a missing feature in the standard C++ library that was known to be
missing in libstdc++4.6 and implemented in libstdc++4.7. There are numerous
C++11 problems with 4.6's library, and we don't support GCCs or libstdc++ older
than 4.7. You will need to update your system and ensure Clang uses the newer
standard library.
```

what am I doing wrong ? how do I install libstdc++4.7 ?
using centos 6.

Comment: Install newer version of gcc - you can find instructions here http://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

Comment: it wasn't working - getting 404 error - but finally, I figure it out - add my solution there...